# Enable react render or disable it at event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a popup menu and I don't know how to make it pop on or out :D.
I was thinking to make some sort of `onclick={handleClick()}` which will contain some sort of code that will turn the renderer on or off.
This is my react code

```
    class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        //a javascript object
        objects: [
            {
                option: 'Edit Event',
            },
            {
                option: 'Delete Event',
            },
        ]
    }
    cancelHandler() {
        display(none);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="popUp">
                <div className="object">
                    {
                        this.state.objects.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={index} className="container">
                                    <p className="menuItems">{item.option}</p>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="cancel-button">
                    <p className="cancel">Cancel</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('menu'));
```

What I want to happen is when I press on the cancel `p` tag all of the elements on the page to disappear(the ones in this file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to do in following way with Boolean variable and a function as you needed

```
  class App extends React.Component {
      this.state = {
          renderElements: true,
          objects: [
             {
                 option: 'Edit Event',
        },
        {
            option: 'Delete Event',
        },
        ]
      }
      cancelHandler = () => {
          this.setState({ 
               renderElements: false
          });
       }
      render() {
            const { renderElements} this.state;
            return (
                <div className="popUp">
                    { renderElements && (<div className="object">
                      {
                    this.state.objects.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index} className="container">
                                <p className="menuItems">{item.option}</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
            <div className="cancel-button">
                <p className="cancel" onClick={this.cancelHandler}>Cancel</p>
            </div>
           )}
        </div>
           );
       }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('menu'));
```

This functionality will hide when you click cancel otherwise shown

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but maybe this is what you want?

```
    class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    //a javascript object
    showObjects: true,
    objects: [
        {
            option: 'Edit Event',
        },
        {
            option: 'Delete Event',
        },
    ]
}
cancelHandler() {
    display(none);
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="popUp">
            <div className="object">
                {this.state.showObjects && 
                    this.state.objects.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index} className="container">
                                <p className="menuItems">{item.option}</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
            <div className="cancel-button">
                <p onClick={() => this.setState({showObjects: false})} className="cancel">Cancel</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Basically I just Add a showObjects flag.